# How to separate a List into Multiple Columns using R

Tags: r, tidyr

One of the column in the dataset, currently consists of a list. I would like to convert it into multiple columns.

**Sample Column Data**:

```
[2060657.4999428242, 2143589.028916441, 2196493.4902963564, 2316188.419917967, 2130287.151382759, 1852280.080035247]
```

I currently use 'tidyr' package in R to split this list into Multiple Columns;

```
Output <- Output %>% separate(amount, c("TA0", "TA1", "TA2", "TA3", "TA4", "TA5", "TA6"),
                           extra = 'drop', fill = 'left')
```

I am obtaining a multiple columns, but, with different result, such as;

```
| TA0 | TA1    | TA2       | TA3    | TA4      | TA5      | TA6     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  NA   1839801  6996446848   1901519  605394691   1798929  9497592524
```

Whereas, the output should be the same as provided in the dataset. The values obtained are changed drastically.

I do understand that, there is a problem with my Code, but, I am unable to figure out how do I rectify it.

Any inputs will be really helpfull.

*Edited* based on Comments.

Comment: How would the desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an unwanted list column that you want to transform to multiple columns.  You didn't provide reproducible data, so I will create this situation with the `iris` dataset.

#### Create a dataset with a numeric list-column

```
example_data <-
    iris %>%
    mutate(list_col = list(rnorm(7)))
```

This example assumes your data in the column in question is actually a *list*.  The unwanted list-column is called `list_col`.  So example data looks like:

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species list_col 
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <list>   
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  <dbl [7]>
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  <dbl [7]>
# ... with 140 more rows
```

#### Create column names

Next, tell R the new column names you'd like to add.

```
my_new_column_names <- c("TA0", "TA1", "TA2", "TA3", "TA4", "TA5", "TA6")
```

Please note the length of the random lists I've added to `iris` to create `example_data` is equal to the number of new column (names) we are assuming.  Also, the length of the list in each row of the dataframe is the same.

#### Isolate the list data (i.e. the list-column) and manipulate into a new dataframe

```
new_df <- example_data %>%
    pull(list_col) %>%
    map(. , ~{setNames(.x, my_new_column_names)}) %>%
    map(., ~{.x %>% t %>% as.tibble}) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

Here, `pull()` just isolated the list-column, then the first `map()` sets the name of each list element to be what is specified in `my_new_column_names`.  The second `map()` converts the lists to dataframes.  For each list (i.e. each row of the original `example_data`), we don't want single-column dataframes with 7 values and named rows, we want a single-row dataframe with 7 columns, so we need the `t` function to transpose each list.

The final bind_rows() just converts the list of 1×7 dataframes into a single multi-row dataframe.

(This step could probably be improved, but this should work.)

#### Add the new data back to the original

The last step is to add the now-properly-formatted data back to your original data, and to remove the list-column, which is now superfluous.

```
corrected_data <- example_data %>%
    bind_cols(new_df) %>%
    select(-list_col)
```

The `corrected_data` should now look like

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 12]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 150 x 12
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     TA0    TA1
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  -0.170   0.225
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa   1.32   -2.00 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  -0.517   1.60 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa   0.0867 -0.473
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa   0.138   0.213
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  -0.213   0.892
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  -0.804  -1.34 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa   0.754  -2.57 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  -0.138   1.11 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  -0.814   1.24 
# ... with 140 more rows, and 5 more variables: TA2 <dbl>, TA3 <dbl>,
#   TA4 <dbl>, TA5 <dbl>, TA6 <dbl>
```

... which I think is what you want.

If you want to smash it all together into one string of piped functions, it would look like

```
example_data %>%
        pull(list_col) %>%
        map(. , ~{setNames(.x, my_new_column_names)}) %>%
        map(., ~{.x %>% t %>% as.tibble}) %>%
        bind_rows() %>%
        bind_cols(example_data, .) %>%
        select(-list_col)
```